# Elasticsearch query based on result of initial query

Tags: search, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

I have an interesting problem, I have an Elasticsearch query which brings back whatever results, however, some of these results have have other results associated with them, like comments associated with a forum post.

If a forum post is matched by my query, I want it to also match the associated comments, which all have a `parent_id` of the original forum post.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

In case anybody comes across this in the future, here is the answer!

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-inner-hits.html#parent-child-inner-hits